# class ViewController has no intitalizers

Tags: swift, view, controller

Here is the line of code causing the error

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

I'm following a tutorial so I can't imagine why this went wrong.
It was working just fine until I added this function into my code:

```
     //Check if user is already logged in when opening app if so display dashboard page
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil{
        if self.theUser.user_db_obj.email == "mike@chicagodrumlessons.com"{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("adminLogin", sender: self) //dislay admin page
        }
        else{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("userLogin", sender: self)  //display user page
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the only lines of code where the delegate is referenced I believe

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.email_tf.delegate = self
    self.pass_tf.delegate = self
}
```

Any idea what caused this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you declare non-optional properties and they aren't initialized when the object is. The compiler is telling you you need an init or two to provide the non-optional properties values before the object can be initialized (or make the properties optionals).

Comment: You were right I found it thanks for that, that really helped me out actually.